# http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response, python, pycharm

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
```

error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayaP8.png)
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

hello, when I try to open chromedriver, it fails and throws errors, so how can I solve it? thanks